# Import CSV with variable columns into Sql Database using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to import csv files from blob storage into a sql server database using Azure Data Factory.  These csv files do not have a consistent format.  Not all csv files have the same number of columns.

How can I check to see if a column exists in the csv file and if it doesn't just insert a NULL value for that column into the SQL Server database?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using ADF v2.

You can see the column presence by clicking on the ADF activity and then going to Mapping tab, it will enable you to map the columns present in CSV file with the input dataset and from there you will be able to know if there are any missing columns as the mapping would fall short for columns from input file.

If you don't see any mapping present already, then you need to click on Import Schemas to map the file columns with input dataset.

To insert a NULL value in database, you can write a stored procedure and call that via ADF or you can keep the database column with a default value as NULL, so if the data is not present in the file for that column, then automatically it will take value as NULL.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Thanks and Regards,

Pratik Somaiya

Comment: Let me clarify.  Sometimes my csv file doesn't have the column at all.   So, the ADF is giving me a UserErrorInvalidColumnMappingColumnNotFound error.

Comment: okay, but the problem is ADF follows a dataset format, so you will have to specify the number of columns in the input dataset, your file should match that number. As I see, the file is quite dynamic in nature, not having fixed number of columns you can use the dynamic functionality of ADF. You will have to try following expression in "translator" part of copy activity, you can tweak it according to your use case: @json(activity('FetchingColumnMapping').output.firstRow.ColumnMapping)

Answer (score 0):

somaiya,

I didn't understand how I could apply your solution in the translator

```
you can tweak it according to your use case: @json(activity('FetchingColumnMapping').output.firstRow.ColumnMapping)
```

In my scenario, CSV file has rows with 10 columns and other rows with 23 columns. Thus, when I run the pipeline, I got the error below:

UserErrorInvalidColumnMappingColumnNotFound error

So, how would I CSV add all 23 columns to the output table (i.e. sink), assigning "null" to the columns of the rows, which have only 8 total?

The translatos chunk (json) has only 10 columns

```
 "translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "mappings": [
            {
                "source": {
                    "type": "String",
                    "ordinal": 1
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "Prop_0",
                    "type": "String",
                    "physicalType": "nvarchar"
                }
            },
            ...
            {
                "source": {
                    "type": "String",
                    "ordinal": 10
                },
                "sink": {
                    "name": "Prop_9",
                    "type": "String",
                    "physicalType": "nvarchar"
                }
            }
        ],
```

The CSV looks like as following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@pratik-somaiya
So far, I figured out how to add apply it, in my piepline activity.

```
...
"translator": {
                "value": "@json(activity('FetchingColumnMapping').output.firstRow.ColumnMapping)",
                "type": "Expression"
            }
....
```

However, it returns an error as following:

"The output of activity 'FetchingColumnMapping' can't be referenced since it is either not an ancestor to the current activity or does not exist."

[image]

Pipeline code has been attached below:

```
{
"name": "pipeline2",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "FetchingColumnMapping",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings",
                        "skipLineCount": 3
                    }
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
                },
                "enableStaging": false,
                "translator": {
                    "value": "@json(activity('FetchingColumnMapping').output.firstRow.ColumnMapping)",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "CSV_DelimitedText",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlBlob",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "folder": {
        "name": "DEV/IURI"
    },
    "annotations": []
 }
}
```